# Why either of odd or even convergents lie on a line?

Tags: continued-fractions

On the geometrical interpretation of continued fractions we can see the following facts ($\alpha$ is an irrational number) :

1- The line $y=\alpha x$ never passes through a lattice point $\alpha$ is an irrational number.

2- Considering the convergents of $\alpha$, i.e. the numbers $c_i = \frac{p_i}{q_i}$, the points $(q_{2k-1}, p_{2k-1})$ are the lattice points which all lie below the line $y=\alpha x$; and, the points $(q_{2k}, p_{2k})$ are the lattice points which all lie above the line $y=\alpha x$.

3- a) All the points $(q_{2k-1}, p_{2k-1})$ all lie on a single straight line and all the points $(q_{2k}, p_{2k})$ all lie on a(nother) single straight line; and b) these two mentioned lines approach the line $y=\alpha x$ more and more closely the farther out we go.

All the claims in 1, 2 and 3 are from Felix Klein a popular mathematical expositor. I could prove all but the 3-a.

Please help for a proof of why either of all the relevant lattice points even or odd convergents are on a line? Thank you.

Added; that's enough to prove (for example in case of evens) that $$\dfrac{p_{2k}-p_{2k-2}}{q_{2k}-q_{2k-2}}=\dfrac{p_{2k+2}-p_{2k}}{q_{2k+2}-q_{2k}}$$ but I am stuck in it!

Comment: Don't the straight lines approach $y=\alpha x$ ? So, they should reach $y=\alpha x$ at $\infty$. Anyway, "reach it at infinity" is un unlucky formulation.

Comment: Are the points actually on a straight line or only approximately ? For example, the convergents $(3/2),(17/12),(99/70)$ of $\sqrt{2}$ are not on a straigt line.

Comment: @Peter, they are not on a straight line as after your comment I looked at the book again as written "a polygonal path which approaches the line y = ax". By the way, if it was a straight line then I arrive to a contradiction, i.e. $a_{2k+2} \times  a_{2k+1} \times  a_{2k} = 0$ for all $k \ge 1$ (!!). - Problem solved! Thank you :)

Comment: And the author doesn't use the formulation "reach it at infinity", right ?

Comment: @Peter, I edited it by a copy-paste from the book. Thanks.